# Post Editor not working on WordPress 3.5.1

Tags: wp-admin

Recently i have updated my wp site to the latest version and since then post editor not working,

**What i have tried:**

- Disabled all plugins.
- Installed "Use Google Libraries".
- Disable all plugins except "Use Google Libraries".
- Re-install WordPress from the update panel.

**Followed some solutions on WordPress support:**

Adding this line in wp-config.php

Solution #1:

```
define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);
```

Solution #2:

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );
```

i have tried all of the above methods and none of them worked for me.
please help me with this issue because i can't able to update my website :(

Comment: Disable _Use Google Libraries_ too. That’s not useful.

Comment: ok, disabled all plugins but visual editor still not working.

Comment: What browser are you using? If you have a console, are there any errors shown in the console?

Comment: I'm using firefox,
the default web console for firefox doesn't show any JS error

Comment: The first thing I think with these "I just updated" problems is that something went wrong with the update. Have you tried re-uploading (over FTP) all of the Core files?

Comment: no i didn't use FTP, i use the update option from the dashboard (wp-admin/update-core.php)

Comment: should i upload core files again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is embarrassing.
I found the culprit, it was one of my theme :(
Enabling Twenty Twelve solves the visual editor issue.

Sorry guyz and thanks for the support.